# Adding leading '0' to format till a 5 digit number value

Tags: vba, excel

Currently I managed to develop a alphanumeric kind of ID. But I tried running a few times and found out sometimes the numeric values will only show 4 digits (Assuming one 0 did is not inputted) so was I am lacking of that one code to help me to make it to 5 digits, any one mind to give me that golden piece of code? Thanks

**Here is my current code**

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open() ' Called every time you open the Excel document
    Dim alpha As String
    Dim numeric As Long
    Dim alphanumeric As String
    Randomize
    numeric = CLng(Rnd() * 99999)   ' CLng converts the floating point number to a long integer
    alpha = "SCC"
    alphanumeric = alpha & numeric

    Dim rowNum As Integer
    Dim colNum As Integer
    rowNum = 6
    colNum = 4

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(rowNum, colNum)
        If (.Value = "") Then
            .Value = alphanumeric
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change this line of code

```
alphanumeric = alpha & numeric
```

into

```
alphanumeric = alpha & Format(numeric,"0000") '<~or into any number of zeros you prefer
```

Comment: yes, this is the piece of golden code that im looking for. thanks once again Romcel!

Answer (score 4):

Replace

```
alphanumeric = alpha & numeric
```

with

```
alphanumeric = alpha & Format(numeric, "00000")
```

this will always return a 5 digit number

Comment: awesome! Thank you as well!